# How to disable the addition of "Vary: Accept-Encoding" to the output when using "zlib.output_compression=On"?

Tags: php, nginx

[zlib.output_compression](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression):

> Whether to transparently compress pages. If this option is set to "On"
>   in php.ini or the Apache configuration, pages are compressed if the
>   browser sends an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" or "deflate" header.
>   "Content-Encoding: gzip" (respectively "deflate") and "Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding" headers are added to the output. In runtime, it can
>   be set only before sending any output.

Comment: You have maybe problem which is possible solve it by another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php) is exactly writen how it works.

> zlib.output_compression boolean/integer Whether to transparently
>   compress pages. If this option is set to "On" in php.ini or the Apache
>   configuration, pages are compressed if the browser sends an
>   "Accept-Encoding: gzip" or "deflate" header. "Content-Encoding: gzip"
>   (respectively "deflate") and "Vary: Accept-Encoding" headers are added
>   to the output. In runtime, it can be set only before sending any
>   output.

By me its impossible change this logics. Otherway is to change PHP source code, recompile it and use it as you need. But this must be done manually after each PHP update. Not good way.